# Como heredar el evento click a todos los hijos de un contenedor?

Tags: javascript, onclicklistener

tengo el siguiente codigo simple de ejemplo, lo que quiero es que los hijos del div hereden el evento click del container sin tener que hacer un listener para cada uno, ni usar css para que los hijos abarquen todo el ancho de la caja, etc

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    *{
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html,body{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: var(--light);
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .container{
      width: 300px;
      background:steelblue;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    .something{
      background: tomato;
      padding: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="something">xxx</div>
    <div class="something">x</div>
  </div>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener("click", e =>{
      if(e.target.matches(".container")) alert();
    })
  </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

lo unico que se me ocurre es esto, que por cierto creo que es como agregar un listener a cada elemento y de seguro hay una solucion mas elegante por asi decirlo?

```
  <div class="container click">
    <div class="something click">xxx</div>
    <div class="something click">x</div>
  </div>

    document.addEventListener("click", e =>{
      if(e.target.matches(".click")) alert();
    })
```

ahora, un caso donde no sabria como solucionarlo es en este

```
<body>
  <div class="general">
    <div class="container click">
      <div class="something click">xxx</div>
      <div class="something click">x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="next">ʘ‿ʘ</div>
    <div class="container click">
      <div class="something click">xxx</div>
      <div class="something click">x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="next">ʘ‿ʘ</div>
    <div class="container click">
      <div class="something click">xxx</div>
      <div class="something click">x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="next">ʘ‿ʘ</div>
  </div>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener("click", e =>{
      if(e.target.matches(".click")) e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hidden");
    })
  </script>
  
</body>
```

el evento click funcionaria correctamente para el container pero no para sus hijos, como se podria solucionar en este caso si tengo varios triggers como en el ejemplo?
Por eso pienso que debe haber una solucion mas simple, como anular que los hijos del container tomen el evento click o algo por el estilo, debe ser una situacion comun que se le habra presentado a miles.

Comment: puedes usar `document.getElementsByClassName()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A menos que uses [funciones flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), la función usará `this` para hacer referencia al elemento al que se asigna el evento y, por defecto, el evento se va a disparar independientemente de que se haga clic en el contenedor o en sus hijos.

"La magia" está en asignar el evento con función "no-flecha" para que, dentro de la función, `this` apunte al contenedor y no al elemento que dispara el evento.

```js
function toggleHide(e) {
    // this hace referencia al elemento definido al asignar el evento
    // No importa si es el contenedor o sus hijos
    // e.target hace referencia al elemento que realmente disparó el evento
    console.log(this, e.target);
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hidden");
}

document.querySelectorAll('.container')
    .forEach(container => container.addEventListener('click', toggleHide));
```

```css
*{
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html,body{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: var(--light);
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .container{
      width: 300px;
      background:steelblue;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    .something{
      background: tomato;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    .hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="general">
    <div class="container click">
        <div class="something">xxx</div>
        <div class="something">x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="next">ʘ‿ʘ</div>
    <div class="container click">
        <div class="something">xxx</div>
        <div class="something">x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="next">ʘ‿ʘ</div>
    <div class="container click">
        <div class="something">xxx</div>
        <div class="something">x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="next">ʘ‿ʘ</div>
</div>
```

Usando funciones flecha también puedes lograrlo, pero complicas la lógica, porque tienes que detectar el padre:

- `e.target` es el elemento que disparó el evento
- Debes analizar si tiene la clase `container`
- De lo contrario, buscar el padre con [.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.container')
    .forEach(container => container.addEventListener('click', e => {
        // Elemento que disparó el evento
        let target = e.target;
        // Si no es el contenedor, obtenerlo
        if(!target.classList.contains('container')) {
            // Obtener el contenedor padre
            target = e.target.closest('.container');
        }
        target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hidden");
    }));
```

```css
*{
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html,body{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: var(--light);
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .container{
      width: 300px;
      background:steelblue;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    .something{
      background: tomato;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    .hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="general">
    <div class="container click">
        <div class="something">xxx</div>
        <div class="something">x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="next">ʘ‿ʘ</div>
    <div class="container click">
        <div class="something">xxx</div>
        <div class="something">x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="next">ʘ‿ʘ</div>
    <div class="container click">
        <div class="something">xxx</div>
        <div class="something">x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="next">ʘ‿ʘ</div>
</div>
```

Comment: pero yo estoy usando el listener delegado al document, ahi creo solo corre el e.target, el this seria el propio document, cierto?

Answer (score 3):

he encontrado una solucion la cual aprendi en un video de un curso de js de jonmircha, por cierto muy recomendable el curso, y la dejo aqui por si alguien le sirve.
La clave esta en hacer que el e.target sean los elementos que estan dentro del contenedor, esto se consigue con *, y entonces para apuntar al nextElementSibling uso la propiedad parentElement de los nodos hijos. dejo el ejemplo final:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    *{
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html,body{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: var(--light);
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .container{
      width: 300px;
      background:steelblue;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      /* padding: 8px; */
    }
    .something{
      flex-grow: 1;
      background: tomato;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    .another{
      background: burlywood;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    .next{
      background: aqua;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 10px;
    }
    .hidden{
      visibility: hidden;
    }
  </style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="general">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="something">xxx</div>
      <div class="another">x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="next">ʘ‿ʘ</div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="something">xxx</div>
      <div class="another">x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="next">ʘ‿ʘ</div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="something">xxx</div>
      <div class="another">x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="next">ʘ‿ʘ</div>    
  </div>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener("click", e =>{
      if(e.target.matches(".container *")) e.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hidden");
    })
  </script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

creo que es ECMAScript 6, ahora se logra que todos los hijos y futuros hijos hereden el eventos click del padre:

```
const lista = document.getElementById('lista');
const btnAgregar = document.getElementById('btn-agregar');

/*aquì agrega hijos*/

btnAgregar.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const elemento = `
        <a href="#">
            Elemento <i class="bi bi-check-square-fill"></i>
        </a>
    `;
    lista.innerHTML += elemento;
});

/*agrega una sola vez el evento click al Nodo Padre llamado: lista*/

lista.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log(e.target);
});
```